# Extract word from string Using python regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract a Model Number from string ,

```
/dev/sda:

ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       ST500DM002-1BD142                       
    Serial Number:      W2AQHKME
    Firmware Revision:  KC45    
    Transport:          Serial, SATA Rev 3.0
```

Regex I wrote,

```
re.search("Model Number:(\s+[\w+^\w|d]\n\t*)", str)
```

But issue is, its not matching any special characters (non ascii) in string str

**Python 2.6**

**Note: String can be combination any characters/digits (including special)**

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3? What sample input can you give us that *doesn't* match?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Python 2.6

Comment: Are your strings `unicode` objects or byte strings?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have posted the string above. Sorry I dont understand what you are asking for

Comment: Note that `[\w+^\w|d]` is **not** a grouping but a *character class*. You are matching **one** character that is a member of the set `\w`, `+`, `^`, `|` or `d`.

Comment: *special* has no pre-defined meaning, and I took it to mean *not-ASCII*. What do *you* mean by it?

Comment: I meant `-` or `/` or `#` @MartijnPieters

Comment: Then why the *non-ASCII* qualifier? You mean *not letters or digits* instead? Non-ASCII means you have Latin-1 or higher codepoints, and thus either 8-bit byte string data or `unicode` objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your regex would be,

```
Model Number:\s*([\w-]+)
```

Python code would be,

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """
... 
... /dev/sda:
... 
... ATA device, with non-removable media
...     Model Number:       ST500DM002-1BD142                       
...     Serial Number:      W2AQHKME
...     Firmware Revision:  KC45    
...     Transport:          Serial, SATA Rev 3.0"""
>>> m = re.search(r'Model Number:\s*([^\n]+)', s)
>>> m.group(1)
'ST500DM002-1BD142'
```

**Explanation:**

- `Model Number:\s*` Matches the string `Model Number:` followed by zero or more spaces.
- `([^\n]+)` Captures any character but not of a newline character one or more times.

Comment: It fails in case of word separated with spaces `Model Number:  Virtual Box`

Comment: @Pilot use `[-\s\w]+` in that case.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Results `'Model Number:       ST500DM002-1BD142         \n\tSerial Number'`

Comment: @Pilot use `Model Number:\s*([^\n]+)`

Comment: sure. May i add that to my answer.