# How to extract words from bytes using regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

I've a bytes:

> b'\n\x1b\t\xff\xff\xff\x7f@^\x8a?\x11\x00\x00\x00@\xe8HL\xbf\x19\x00\x00\x00\x00\x95\xb0\xd9?\x127\r\xc9\xd5"=\x15\xc9\xd5"=\x1a+\x1a)\n\x1e\x12\x1c\n\x0fMovies"\x07Bollard0\x01\x11\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?'
> b'\n\x1b\t\x01\x00\x00\x00\xa4\x9b\xb0\xbf\x11\x01\x00\x00\xc0/\xe3\x90?\x19\x01\x00\x00\xa0U\xc4\xef?\x127\r|\x934=\x15|\x934=\x1a+\x1a)\n\x1e\x12\x1c\n\x0fMovies"\x07TV Series0\x01\x11\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?'

Using regex, I want to extract words(in this case "Movies", "Movies" and "TV Series")

What I tried:

[Extract word from string Using python regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885262/extract-word-from-string-using-python-regex)

[Extracting words from a string, removing punctuation and returning a list with separated words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633274/extracting-words-from-a-string-removing-punctuation-and-returning-a-list-with-s)

[Python regex for finding all words in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37543724/python-regex-for-finding-all-words-in-a-string)

Comment: It is not clear what you are doing and why you expect just `Movies` and `TV Series`. Please show your code and explain what does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you would convert bytes into a string using the `.decode()` method. However, your bytes contain values that are not ASCII or UTF-8.

My suggestion is to go through each byte and try interpreting it as an ASCII value

```
raw= b'\n\x1b\t\xff\xff\xff\x7f@^\x8a?\x11\x00\x00\x00@\xe8HL\xbf\x19\x00\x00\x00\x00\x95\xb0\xd9?\x127\r\xc9\xd5"=\x15\xc9\xd5"=\x1a+\x1a)\n\x1e\x12\x1c\n\x0fMovies"\x07Bollard0\x01\x11\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?' b'\n\x1b\t\x01\x00\x00\x00\xa4\x9b\xb0\xbf\x11\x01\x00\x00\xc0/\xe3\x90?\x19\x01\x00\x00\xa0U\xc4\xef?\x127\r|\x934=\x15|\x934=\x1a+\x1a)\n\x1e\x12\x1c\n\x0fMovies"\x07TV Series0\x01\x11\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?'
string = ""
for b in raw:
    string += chr(b)
print(string)
```

After that, you can use a Regex approach to find words. It's usually a good idea to define a minimum length for a word.

```
import re
for word in re.split('\W', string):
    if len(word) > 3:
        print(word)
```

That will give you:

```
Movies
Bollard0
Movies
Series0
```

You have not mentioned "Bollard0", but I assume that was a mistake.

If you want spaces to be part of your string, you'll need to adapt the Regex. `\W` splits on word boundaries and Space is considered a boundary.